# Geowebcache Openlayers integration

Tags: openlayers, geowebcache

I cached my map hoping to use it with openlayers. This is my code below.

```
    var layers = [
    new ol.layer.Image({
      source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: 'http://0.0.0.0:8080/geoserver/wms',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'silapha:basemap'},
        ratio: 1,
        serverType: 'geoserver'
      })
    })
  ];

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: layers,
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [0, 869099],
      zoom: 7
    })
  });
```

This still renders the old uncached layer. I enable direct wms integration  as well but I can't just render the cached map.

This this is the url to the cached map and the preview works well. 
`http://0.0.0.0:8080/geoserver/gwc/demo/silapha:basemap?gridSet=EPSG:900913&format=image/png`

What have i done wrong, what should add to the code to get the cache tile rendering instead of the uncached one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in this [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-tiled.html) you need to use a `Tile Layer` with a `TileWMS source`:

```
new ol.layer.Tile({
      extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
      source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wms',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'topp:states', 'TILED': true},
        serverType: 'geoserver'
      })
    })
  ];
```

By using an `ImageWMS Source` you request one big image which will always defeat the cache.

Comment: It works so smoothly. So the problem is with `ImageWMS` instead of `TileWMS`

Answer (score 0):

I believe I read the question a little differently and that you want to retrieve your layers from geowebcache, rather than using tiled wms. This [example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wmts.html) will do that, and show how to set up the tilegrid.

```
var mylayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.WMTS({
        url: 'http://0.0.0.0:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts',
        layer: 'silapha:basemap',
        format: 'image/png',
        matrixSet: 'EPSG:900913',
        tileGrid: tileGrid,
    })
});
```